# Set default value to option select menu with Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I get all the categories:

```
const getCategories = async () => {
  let response = await axios.get(`/api/get_all_category/`)
  categories.value = response.data.categories
}
```

categories.value looks like this:

[image]

I set the default option:

```
let selectedCategory
const getSingleProduct = async () => {
  let response = await axios.get(`/api/get_edit_product/${props.id}`)
  form.value = response.data.product
   
  //form.value.category_id is a number from 1 to 6
  selectedCategory = ref(form.value.category_id) 
}
```

I build the select tag:

```
<div class="my-3">
  <p>Product type</p>
  <select v-model="selectedCategory">
    <option v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" :value="category.id">
      {{ category.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I can see all the options correctly but the default option is not set accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first to define `selectedCategory` as reactive with `ref`:

```js
const { ref, computed } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const categories = ref([{id: 1, name: 'aaa'}, {id: 2, name: 'bbb'}, {id: 3, name: 'ccc'}])
    let selectedCategory = ref(null)
    const getSingleProduct = () => {
      //let response = await axios.get(`/api/get_edit_product/${props.id}`)
     // form.value = response.data.product
      //form.value.category_id is a number from 1 to 6
       selectedCategory.value = 3
    }
    getSingleProduct()
    return { categories, selectedCategory }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="my-3">
    <p>Product type</p>
    <select v-model="selectedCategory">
      <option v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" :value="category.id" :selected="selectedCategory">
        {{ category.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this using Composition API.

Comment: @erohtpur hey mate , my demo is in composition api :)